# Firebase Java API removeValue not working

Tags: java, firebase

I'm relative new to Firebase so appreciate any insight on this one. When I call the Firebase setValue(obj, callback) function in this manner it works perfectly. However, when I tried to remove the value referenced by "ref" nothing happens. This is just a test account so I have my security rules set to full read and write. The output is below. Some of the output comes from an encapsulating run() method that call removeNode(...). Any insights much appreciated.

```
public void removeNode(final Firebase ref) throws Exception {

    try {
        System.out.println("Start Remove Node: " + ref.toString());

        final AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        ref.removeValue(new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
                done.set(true);
                System.out.println("Remove Node complete");
                if (firebaseError != null) {
                    System.out.println("ErrorCode: " + firebaseError.getCode());
                    System.out.println("ErrorMsg: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
                }
                System.out.println("Remove Complete Done");
            }
        });
        while (!done.get()) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println("Remove Node Sleeping");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Remove Node Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My output is as follows:

```
in run() - about to removeNode https://<instance>.firebaseio.com/node/node
Start Remove Node: https://<instance>.firebaseio.com/node/node
Remove Node Sleeping
Remove Node Sleeping
Remove Node complete
Remove Complete Done
Remove Node Sleeping
in run() - RemoveNode leaving normally
pool-3-thread-1
All threads handled so far? {true}
Complete

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Note: I have similar results with this.

```
ref.setValue(null, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
                done.set(true);
                System.out.println("setNull Node complete");
                if (firebaseError != null) {
                    System.out.println("ErrorCode: " + firebaseError.getCode());
                    System.out.println("ErrorMsg: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("FirebaseError: NULL");
                }
                System.out.println("setNull Complete Done");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/RItU7nD-PjM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Firebase URL used to remove is https://BLAH/node/node

is it supposed to be https://BLAH/node?

Take the URL and paste it in your browser to view it in Forge and double check the data is there.

Comment: My URL is deliberately https://blah/node/node so that is not the issue but your tip pointed me in the right direction.

When using curl or a direct browser link I get back the expected value or in this case lack of value: null. However, in the dashboard I see a cached version of the data that is not updated to reflect the data change.

Comment: Continued: Simple refreshes, log in/out do not seem to work to update the Forge data. Is there a trick to fresh the Forge data presentation and clear its cache?

Thanks!

Comment: Continued: I figured it out. the url https://<instance>.firebaseio.com/ takes care of the root node. I was attempting to access 

https://<instance>.firebaseio.com/<instance>/node when I really only need to access https://<instance>.firebaseio.com/node

Thanks!